# How to add space in alphabets and digits using regex python

Tags: python, string

I want to separate string from the digits using regex. I don't want to replace anything just add space. I don't want to add space in digit and special character or string and special character.
for example

```
 "A-21PHASE-1,ASHOK VIHARA-21, PHASE-1, - ASHOK VIHAR110052"
```

output for above example should look like,

```
"A-21 PHASE-1,ASHOK VIHARA-21, PHASE-1, - ASHOK VIHAR 110052"
```

in this example I want to add space between alphabets and number. there are number attached with '-' or any special character , I don't want to do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User re.sub:

```
thestring = re.sub(r'(\d)([A-Z])', r'\1 \2', thestring)
thestring = re.sub(r'([A-Z])(\d)', r'\1 \2', thestring)
```

First one puts spaces between digits and capital letters, second one between capital letters and digits.